# Outputting datetime in a loop is failing

Tags: python, datetime

My aim is to run ipconfig every 10 seconds for 1000 times, writing the output of the command to a text file containing the date. The problem with my code below is that once it begins the 2nd run through of the loop, it coughs up:

> datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'datetime'

```
import datetime
import os
import time

count=0
while (count < 1000):
    print '--------------------------------------------------------'
    print count
    datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
    print datetime
    os.system("ipconfig > ipconfig_" + datetime)
    print '--------------------------------------------------------'
    time.sleep(10)
    count = count + 1
print "Good bye!"
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: `datetime = datetime.datetime`... You just overwrote the imported module. Use a different variable name

Comment: it a bad idea to use builtin names as variable name, you can use something like `datetime_now`

Comment: Also, `for count in range(1000)` would be the suggested way to write that loop

Comment: Thank you - that's fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are re-using the datetime variable in the code. In the first run, it works fine because datetime is the imported module. Then, on

```
datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
# datetime is now a string storing the date time in the format specified
```

In the second run, the code now crashes in the rhs of the same line as there is no property datetime in the string datetime

Fixed code:

```
import datetime
import os
import time

count=0
while (count < 1000):
    print '--------------------------------------------------------'
    print count
    date_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
    print date_time
    os.system("ifconfig > ifconfig_" + date_time)
    print '--------------------------------------------------------'
    time.sleep(10)
    count = count + 1
print "Good bye!"
```